# Laravel max validation doesn't take effect on file upload and I can still upload images that are bigger than the limit. Why is this happening?

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following rule:

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        'files' => 'required|max:5000'
    ]);
```

If I'm not wrong, this allows for files that are up to 5MB to be uploaded and it should return an error if it's above that. However, I can still upload 10MB images without any problem.

I don't know if that matters but in my php.ini file I've set post_max_size and upload_max_filesize both to 50M

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="upload-container">
        <form action="{{ route('uploadArtwork') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
                    <button class="btn">Drop files here or click to upload</button>
                    <input class='upload-input' type="file" name='files[]' multiple>
                    @include('partials.invalid', ['field' => 'files'])
                </div>
            </div>

             {{ csrf_field() }}
            <button class='submit-btn' type="submit" name="submit">Publish</button>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: input file name should be also files

Comment: It is, the required rule works.

Comment: Have you added validation type 'file' to the list of validations? .`'files' => 'required|file|max:5000'`?

Comment: what laravel version are you using? it is very good to add the version of laravel as a tag to your question

Comment: The version is 5.5.41. I didn't have the file rule, however, when I added it I started getting the error "The files must be file".

Comment: Oh wait do you have many files being uploaded?

Comment: Well 1 but I'm using "name='files[]' multiple" so if I want I can upload more than 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->validate($request, [
         'files' => 'required',
         'files.*' =>  'required|max:4096',
    ]);
```

Comment: That seems to have worked. Can you tell me what does the second files rule do?

Comment: Usage of an array type input with required and file rule specified without a * doesn't seem to work correctly.

Comment: @Bobimaru Can you include some kind of descriptions of what went wrong and how your piece of code is the solution to help others understand and to discourage just pasting snippets as answer. Thank you.