# Max file size validation in laravel is not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, file, file-upload

I have a simple form to upload the videos. I am trying to check the size of the file.

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

   function submit_videos(Request $req)
{  
    $validated = $req->validate([
        'video_name' => 'required|max:1024'  
    ]);
}
```

The name of the input is `video_name` and the input type is `file`

This accepts files of more than 1MB

Comment: can you post you html code? Like how you are displaying error?

Comment: `'upload' => 'required|file|max:1024',`

Comment: [Laravel max validation doesn't take effect on file upload and I can still upload images that are bigger than the limit. Why is this happening?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58765605/laravel-max-validation-doesnt-take-effect-on-file-upload-and-i-can-still-upload)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `size` rule. This takes an integer value in bytes so that you can specify the maximum allowed file size.

```
$validated = $req->validate([
    'video_name' => 'required|max:1024|size:1048576'  
]);
```